# Not able to view image in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[temp objectForKey:@"distance"] stringByAppendingString:@" km from Banglore"];
    cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your cell's style to `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`

```
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

If you want two labels in the cell, then add it to the `contentView` of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



       // Configure the cell...
        NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
    UIlabel *detailLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,200,50)];
    [detailLbl setText:[[temp objectForKey:@"distance"] stringByAppendingString:@" km from Banglore"];];
[cell.contentView addSubView:detailLbl];
        cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: how to use contentView ?

Comment: The code you posted does not show label and no image also ... i just copy pasted it ,,

Comment: Don't copy paste the code. refer the docs, create a UILabel and add it to the contenctview. [cell.contentView addsubView:yourLabel];

Comment: Solved my label problem .. but image is not showing still. please see to it . @suresh

Comment: The label is getting overlapped with another text , how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Just adjust your label's frame.

Comment: Not that way , when i scroll it overlaps .

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                }

             // Configure the cell...
                NSDictionary *temp = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
                cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"name"];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[temp objectForKey:@"distance"] stringByAppendingString:@" km from Banglore"];
                //cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];

        //write this code 

         // Load the image with an GCD block executed in another thread
            dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("image downloader", NULL);
            dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[temp objectForKey:@"category"]];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                     cell.imageView.image = image;
                     cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                     [cell setNeedsLayout];
                });
            });
            dispatch_release(downloadQueue);

        return cell;

            }
```